# Динамически подставить данные в сообщение

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно, чтобы сообщение менялось динамически.
У меня есть код

```
@dp.message_handler(text = '123')
async def generate(message: types.Message):
    db = fdb.connect(
    dsn=config.connect,
    user=config.user,
    password=config.password,
    charset=config.charset
)
    cur = db.cursor()
    
    res = [LSID for (LSID,) in cur.execute("select lsid from egn_cards where tg_id = 3332 ").fetchall()]
    for item in res:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"text {item}")
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

С его помощью получается такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно чтобы получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен всем, кто поможет. Спасибо

Comment: А при чём тут динамическая подстановка? Судя по скриншотам, вы просто хотите отправить одно сообщение вместо двух — ну значит вынесите send_message из цикла

Comment: Количество лицевых счетов у каждого пользователя будет разным. То есть, вместо двух отдельных сообщений, мне нужно в одном высыпать все. Их может быть как и 2  так и 5.

Comment: Ну вот в цикле собирайте массив/строку и после цикла делайте один send_message со всем собранным

Comment: Я видел подобные подсказки на других форумах, признаюсь честно у меня ничего не вышло. Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой задачей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сперва попробуйте собрать сообщение, а уже потом его отправляйте, примерно так:

```
res = [LSID for (LSID,) in cur.execute("select lsid from egn_cards where tg_id = 3332 ").fetchall()]
    
text =''
for item in res:
    text = text + "\n" + item 
    
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"text {text}")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы помогли.

Comment: Sql - запрос возвращает мне список кортежей. То есть конкатенация невозможна, так как item является tuple . А если обернуть его в str(), дальнейшие действия прекращаются.  Как правильно итерировать, чтобы я мог обращаться к элементам картежа и в  дальнейшем работал с ним.

Comment: @BOLHSOW Так соберите без конкатенации text = f"{text}\n{item}"

Comment: f - строка и есть str. Ничего не изменится.

Comment: В вашем же примере у вас как-то получалось (message.from_user.id, f"text {item}") объединять и отправлять сообщение таким способом, что изменилось?

Comment: Может я не правильно доношу до вас свою мысль. 
В моём примере sql - запрос возвращает мне int(). После вашего ответа, я попробовал прикрутить к другому запросу 
res = cur.execute("SELECT OTVET, LS, ADRES, FIO FROM TG_GET_INFO(11, NULL, ?)", (mes,)).fetchall() который возвращает tuple(). Мне нужно подставить несколько значений в сообщение из этого кортежа. В этом то и проблема, что обратится к str() я не могу. По этому и обратился к вам, так как сам решения найти не смог.

Comment: @BOLHSOW Давайте я вам приведу простой пример: my_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); a, b, c, _ , *z= my_tuple;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150905/discussion-between-bolhsow-and-amgarak).